# Has anyone ever seen this happen in a php freach loop?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I built a multi-dimensional array from a query which has 101 keys

When i echo $result['q101'] before a certain foreach loop it shows the proper data..

after this loop the array is modified somehow to $result['q101'] => 8...???

NOTE: this happens to the last key regardless of the number.

```
> [q99] => Array
>     (
>         [name] => Disentanglement from Love Relationship
>         [abbr] => DfLR
>         [type] => Ascending
>         [response] => Sometimes
>         [score] => 3
>     )
> 
> [q100] => Array
>     (
>         [name] => Feelings of Self Worth
>         [abbr] => FoSW
>         [type] => Ascending
>         [response] => Almost Always
>         [score] => 1
>     )
> 
> [q101] => 8 /// WTF is this..??
```

below is the culprit.. if i remove this everything is hunky dory.

```
foreach ($result as $key => $val){
    $response_table .= '<tr><td>'.str_replace('q', '', $key).'</td><td>'.$val['response'].'</td><td>'.$val['abbr'].'</td><td>'.$val['type'].'</td><td>'.$val['score'].'</td></tr>';
    $min[$val['abbr']] += 1;
    $max[$val['abbr']] += 1;    
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the full code? Are there any foreach loops that uses `$val` by reference? Like this: `$key => &$val`.

Comment: There was... I had no idea this would throw a monkey wrench into the rest of the system. And now that I go back to the manual and see the BIG RED WARNING I am slapping my self...

Comment: I generally add a comment above any `foreach` loop using the by-reference syntax saying "Warning: foreach by reference!" and immediately after the closing `}` add an `unset()` with an appropriate comment saying that it is breaking the reference. References should be used sparingly and carefully - they have all sorts of awkward implications, including a negative impact on performance (the internals are optimised for assign-by-value using a trick called "copy on write").

Comment: @IMSoP - so, if the loop is standard $key => $val then the unset is not necessary correct?

Comment: @SmithSmithy Correct. The `&` is the sign to look out for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are unsetting $key, $val after your foreach.
From http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php
Reference of a $value and the last array element remain even after the foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset().

Comment: how is it assigned by reference? only objects are assigned by reference

Comment: Note that this is only relevant if you use the by-reference syntax (`foreach($result as $key => &$val)` - note the `&`). The code shown in the question doesn't use this, but a previous loop might have done.

Comment: You NAILED IT.. a previous loop used the &$val and I had no idea it remained in tact... Thank You.. It's the little things....

Comment: @Barbara Great answer, continue like this and you'll get lots of rep soon :)

Comment: @DevZer0 That is an incorrect statement on two counts: Firstly, **variables** in PHP are assigned by reference explicitly using `=&`, but also in other cases like the one mentioned. Secondly, this causes assigning a value to either variable to affect both variables - it is effectively one variable with multiple names; this is *not* the same as two variables which both point to the same object - manipulating the object seems to affect both variables, but if you assign a new value to one of the variables, the other is *not* affected. (Unless, of course, it was assigned by reference.)